# Get PDF image DPI c#

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, dpi

I need to get the Image PDF DPI..

am already done 
1. checking whether PDF is image PDF or not.
2. PDF to Image changing time set the DPI.

But I need to get PDF Image DPI? 
Give me the solution in c# with GhostScript,Magick.Net, PDFSharp, iTextSharp
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Stack Overflow is not a free script writing service. Your own research and code attempts are expected. Edit the question to include your code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27938551/162529